# Android Studio UI texts (like filename, options etc) are tiny in MAC

Tags: android, android-studio

All the texts are very tiny in Android Studio. I tried increasing font size by `Preference>Editor>Font>Size` but it increases only the font size of the code. All the other texts like filenames, directories, options etc are still very small. Is there a way to increase the size of all the texts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Preference > Appearance & Behavior > Appearance > Use custom font`

[image]

Note `Editor > Font > Size` is for the editor window (your code).